# How can I group flight legs together into routes for counting?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a person's flight history and want to find their most frequent route. All flights are stored as a single row in a table, even return trips where a->b will be in one row and b->a will be in another.

I need to identify where two legs equate to a route; for example:

This person has flown 16 times in total

- New York to Paris 2 times (Flight key: JFKCDG)
- Paris to New York 2 times (Flight Key: CDGJFK)
- New York to London 3 times (Flight Key: JFKLHR)

Currently I don't know a way to group the first two above as a 'Route' and therefore any query I write considers JFKLHR to be the most frequent route (6 times between NY and London) even though I can see from the data that this person has flown between NY and Paris a total of 10 times

Sample Table:

```
User ID¦Flight Key
-------------------
1      ¦JFKCDG
1      ¦JFKCDG
1      ¦CDGJFK
1      ¦CDGJFK
1      ¦JFKLHR
1      ¦JFKLHR
1      ¦JFKLHR
```

Expected Output

```
User ID¦Flight Key¦Count
------------------------
1      ¦JFKCDGJFK ¦4
```

Comment: MSSQL Server or mySQL or Oracle RDBMS?

Comment: Sample data , Expected output and table structure would be great.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Building on the clever idea in the answer by @fancyPants. You can use string functions to compare each leg of a route and patch together a full return trip.

I believe this query should work. The first part of the common table expression turns those flights that are round trips into three parts (src-dst-src) and the second part returns those that are one way (as src-dst).

```
with flights_cte as (
    select 
       USERID,
       case when left(flightkey,3) > right(flightkey,3) 
          then concat(flightkey, left(flightkey,3)) 
          else concat(right(flightkey,3), flightkey)
       end as flightkey,
       count(*) count
    from flights f
    where exists (
      select 1 from flights where right(f.flightkey,3) = left(flightKey,3)
    )
    group by
       userid, 
       case 
          when left(flightkey,3) > right(flightkey,3) 
             then concat(flightkey, left(flightkey,3)) 
          else concat(right(flightkey,3), flightkey)
       end 
    union all 
    select userid, FlightKey, count(*)
    from flights f 
    where not exists (
      select 1 from flights where right(f.flightkey,3) = left(flightKey,3)
    )
    group by UserID, FlightKey
)

select flights_cte.userid, flights_cte.flightkey, flights_cte.count
from flights_cte
join (select userid, max(count) _max_count from flights_cte group by userid) _max
on flights_cte.UserID=_max.UserID and flights_cte.count = _max_count
```

A sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62e14/2) gives this output:

```
| USERID | FLIGHTKEY | COUNT |
|--------|-----------|-------|
|      1 | JFKCDGJFK |     4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming routes are not a single row, otherwise you wouldn't be asking.. (although I would guess that the whole route is in some other table, maybe reservation-related)

Guessing the first step is to group this data by person and flights that compose a 'route'.  I have an article called [T-SQL: Identify bad dates in a time series](http://rdsrc.us/6IETeo) where the time series can be modified to detect gaps between legs of over a day (guess) to differentiate routes.  Second step would be to convert legs into route, i.e. JFK-CDG and CDG-JFK to single value JFK-CDG-JFK.

Then it would be a single query, counting the above single value route, and ORDER BY that count.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes! If I can group the legs into a route such as JFK-CDG-JFK where JFK-CDG = JFK-CDG-JFK and also CDG-JFK = JFK-CDG-JFK I can do the rest easily